# How do you get the address of an object as an nativeptr in F#?

Tags: pointers, f#, interop, native, unmanaged

I am trying to implement a part of F# code that could benefit from using pointers. Unfortunately, the documentation around unsafe code is poor for the language. I couldn't find any way to properly manage `ilsigptr<T>`, because nothing else seems to be able to convert to it. I tried using a `byref<T>`, since that is what the `&` operator returns, but those aren't allowed as members. `nativeptr<T>` looks promising, but it doesn't have any `ofByRef` function.

Thank you in advance for your help, this has been driving me nuts.

Comment: You can take address of field inside object using `&&obj.Field`. Though I don't recommend it, since object can be moved during garbage collection and this reference won't be valid and can point to entirely different thing

Comment: Perhaps if you elaborate on _why_ you need pointers, a better solution could become apparent.

Comment: https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-nativeinterop-nativeptrmodule.html#ofILSigPtr